# What is the size of pointers in c++?

Tags: c++, null, constants, sizeof

What is the size of pointers in c++?

```
char a;
char *b=a;
cout<<sizeof(b);
```

Output is 2 I don't know why.

```
cout<<sizeof(const);    //o/p is 2
 cout<<sizeof(NULL);   //o/p is 2
```

Comment: Are you using turbo c++ for dos?

Comment: If yes, get rid of it and use a modern compiler.

Comment: Btw. `char *b=a;` should be `char *b=&a;`

Comment: Although `char *b=a;` is not valid.

Comment: It's *implementation-defined* which means that each compiler can make its own decision. Some compilers may let you configure this behaviour (e.g. in Turbo C++ you can select 2 or 4 by specifying a memory model)

Comment: Your compiler lets you use `sizeof(const)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of a pointer in c++ depends on the system you are compiling for and the compiler you are using.

In general, if you are on a 32 bit system the pointer will have a size of 4 bytes. On a 64 bit system it'll be 8 bytes and so on, but that is not guaranteed.

Just use `sizeof(char*)` and you should get the answer.